# Topologies/Norms on Real Closed Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, analysis, field-theory, extension-field

Let $\mathbf{R}$ be a real closed field containing $\Bbb{R}$, and let $\mathbf{C} := \mathbf{R}[i]$. Is there a natural norm or topology on $\mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{C}$?

My interest in this question lies in the fact that I am considering vector spaces over $\mathbf{C}$ with $\mathbf{C}$-valued inner products, and positive operators on such vector spaces. I want to know whether positive operators on such vector spaces are also positive on their completion. I suspect that it is true.

Answer (score 1):

Both ${\bf R}$ and ${\bf C}$ are vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ and as every vector space has a basis they are each isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^I$ for some set $I$.

Let $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^I$. There is an injective map: $$f\colon \mathbb{R}^I\to \prod_{i\in I}\mathbb{R}$$
where for $v\in \mathbb{R}^I$ we let $\{f(v)\}_i$ be the coefficient on $e_i$ of $v$.  Note this map is never surjective if $I$ infinite, as for any $v\in \mathbb{R}^I$ only finitely many of the $\{f(v)\}_i$ are non-zero.

The cartesian product $\prod_{i\in I}\mathbb{R}$ may be regarded as a topological space: formally it is the product $\prod_{i\in I}\mathbb{R}$ in the category of topological spaces.  From this universal property one can easily verify that the open sets in $\prod_{i\in I}\mathbb{R}$ are generated by subsets of the form:$$\prod_{i\in I}U_i$$
where the $U_i\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ are open and for all but finitely many $i\in I$ we have $U_i=\mathbb{R}$.

In summary ${\bf R}$ and ${\bf C}$ may each be identified with a vector space $\mathbb{R}^I$, which inherits a subspace topology from being identified with a subset of the product over $i\in I$ of $\mathbb{R}$ in the category of topological spaces.

Comment: Could you explain (perhaps with an example) how $\mathbb R^I$ is a *subset* of the product of sets $\mathbb R^I$?  Did you mean the product of sets $\mathbb R^i$ where $i\in I$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I have expanded the explanation.

Comment: Thank you ($+1$); why are only finitely many of the $\{f(v)\}_i$ non-zero? because vector addition is defined for only finitely many terms?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks very much.  The definition of a basis of a vector space is a subset such that every element of the vector space may be expressed uniquely as a finite linear combination of vectors in the subset.  The motivation for this definition is probably the reason you suggest.

Comment: @tkf Ah, so you use the vector space isomorphism to put a topology on both $\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{C}$. Is it ever the case that this topology is metrizable or normable (i.e., there is an absolute value for them in the same way $\Bbb{C}$ has an absolute value?)?

Comment: @user193319 I do not think the topology I describe is metrizable - any neighbourhood of the origin will contain an infinite dimensional subspace.  However instead of this topology, you could simply take the Euclidean metric, which is defined as it only involves finite sums.  This will also give you a topology on ${\bf R}$ or ${\bf C}$.

Comment: @tkf Ah, very interesting. Neither $\mathbf{R}$ nor $\mathbf{C}$ will, in general, be complete with respect to that norm, right?

Comment: @user193319 Yes absolutely - you will have "infinite sums" of orthogonal vectors of fast decreasing size, whose partial sums will be Cauchy, but do not have a limit in the space.